# Alternative for finding location of cellphone caller

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I have data from here: http://www.npanxxsource.com/ that returns the lat/lng for a wire center identified by the caller's NPA-NXX. The problem is that cell phone numbers aren't necessarily assigned from the area that NPA-NXX is assigned to.

So is there a better data source available to get a more accurate account of where cell phones are being issued from?

Answer (score 0):

Actually npanxxsource.com's data is extremely accurate. In the United States and Canada NPA-NXX resources/combinations are ALWAYS allocated by Rate Center. The Rate Center is the specific geographic area the NPA-NXX is associated with regardless of telecom carrier or service type (i.e. wireless or landline) thus cell phone numbers for a particular NPA-NXX are always associated with a specific Rate Center.

This holds true even if a telephone number is ported to a different carrier due to the fact that numbers cannot be ported between two different Rate Centers. Also it is important to note that the serving Wire Center may or may not geographically be in the Rate Center therefore you want to use the Rate Center's coordinates not Wire Center's.